# setting maven properties by using shell command

Tags: maven

I would like to obtain a value from a bash shell command and set a property using this value.
I am not sure setting the property is the way to go -- what I am trying to do is obtain a value from a shell command that is executed by Maven and to use this value to name the jar that is created.

More specifically, I would like to obtain using the git describe command the tag of a project and append this tag to the name of the jar.

I would like to do something like this within the pom:

tag = git describe
     .
     .
     .
mv '$jarname'.jar '$jarname$tag'.jar

If I from the command line I execute

mvn jar:jar

I am not sure I can even affect the name of the resultant jar even if I had the git tag,
so that is another question.

Comment: Can you please provide a sketch of what you would like the script / command to look like, as well as the jar name?

Comment: I am thinking this question is misguided. I was able to store the git SHA1 value using the jar plugin which essentially is what I needed.

Comment: @Jeff If you have solved it post your solution also.

Comment: Agreed - you are allowed to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working:

Goal was to be able to store SHA1 and git tag in the manifest of a jar.

Used the Maven plugin found here:

http://code54.com/blog/2012/04/30/buildversion-plugin.html

as well as the Maven buildnumber plugin.

These two plugins respectively set the Maven properties build-tag and buildNumber which
could then be specified in the Maven Jar plugin's manifestEntries section.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many other similar plugins out there, but you can use my [exec-set-property](http://archiecobbs.github.io/dellroad-stuff/site/dellroad-stuff-maven-plugin/) plugin goal to set a Maven property using the output of a shell command.